# Using BridgeKit to start Intent and perform callback with Apportable

Tags: apportable

I'm using BridgeKit to start an Intent which then starts up the Android gallery picker, which then returns the selected image as bytes.

The Intent starts correctly and I can even pick the image and get the PNG representation, but when I try to use a callback to return the bytes to Obj-C land, I get the following error:

```
W/dalvikvm( 3417): No implementation found for native Lmystuff/android/AndroidImageSelector;.imagePicked:([B)V
I/System.out( 3417): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: mystuff.android.AndroidImageSelector.imagePicked:([B)V
```

The Intent is started with:

```
AndroidIntent* intent = [ [AndroidIntent alloc] initWithContext: [ AndroidActivity currentActivity ]  class: [ AndroidImageSelector javaClass ] ];
[intent start];
```

AndroidImageSelector extends JavaObject and includes the following methods:

```
+ (NSString*) className
{
return @"mystuff.android.AndroidImageSelectorActivity";
}


+ (void) initializeJava
{
[ super initializeJava ];

[AndroidImageSelector registerCallback: @"imagePicked"
                     selector: @selector( imagePicked:)
                  returnValue: nil
                    arguments: [NSData className], nil ];
}

- (void) imagePicked: (NSData*) data
{
NSLog( @"IMAGE PICKED: %d", [ data length ] );
}
```

On the Java side AndroidImageSelectorActivity extends Activity and contains:

```
private native void imagePicked( byte[] response );


protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent )
    {
    super.onActivityResult( requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent );

    try
        {
        switch ( requestCode )
            {
            case SELECT_PHOTO:
                if ( resultCode == RESULT_OK )
                    {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

                    Bitmap bitmap = decodeURI( selectedImage );

                    ByteArrayOutputStream out0 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out0 );
                    byte[] pngBytes = out0.toByteArray();

                    imagePicked( pngBytes );
                    }
            }


protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK );
    photoPickerIntent.setType( "image/*" );
    startActivityForResult( photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to have an implementation of imagePicked: on the objective c side. Basically, you've told java that you will provide a native implementation of the java method, but there isn't one.

Comment: Yes, the `imagePicked: (NSData*) data` method is there.  I've updated the code in the question to show it.

Comment: hmmm, there's nothing obviously wrong. if you don't mind, could you email a reduced test case demonstrating the non-functionality to sdk at apportable dot com? mention me in the email and i'll get it shortly after we receive it. after i figure out what's wrong, i'll make sure to email you a solution and update this question with the proper answer. for making the reduced test case, i recommend starting with our hellojava demo app: https://github.com/apportable/HelloJava

Comment: Created a variation of HelloJava which demonstrates the error.  Email on its way.

Comment: Did you find solution? I want look demonstration issue project as well.

Answer (score 1):

This bug will be fixed in the next update of the Apportable SDK. Sorry about that.